# What Azure CDN services support Private Link?

Tags: azure-cdn, azure-front-door, azure-private-link

I see Azure Front Door Premium (CDN) supports Private Link.

For example, Azure Front Door Premium can connect to Azure Storage as its origin via Private Link.

I assume other Azure CDN offerings support Private Link for origins not just Front Door Premium?

That being said, I can't find any documentation on it and don't see the options in Azure Portal.

Am I missing something, or is Front Door Premium the only CDN solution that offers Private Link support currently?

I've tried several other Azure CDN offerings none of them seem to have a Private Link method, which I can't believe.

Comment: Azure Private Link, used to connect the Front Door [Premium] origin group via virtual networks.  You are right this feature is available only on Azure Front door Premium. Share if any errors / issues while configure via private link it will be helping to replicate and suggest solutions.

Comment: Thanks @SwarnaAnipindi I've tested Front Door Premium with Private Link, easy to configure, works great.  I hope MS brings Private Link support to other CDN offerings as Front Door Premium is overkill and costly.  Have to think there are many people who are looking to secure the origin with a basic CDN, say Microsoft CDN (classic).  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your response. Here is the way we can implement the configuration for a private link.

[image]

Currently there are limitations on Private link end point connectivity, because this feature is region agnositc.  Azure Private Link, used to connect the Front door origin group via virtual networks.  This feature is available only on Azure Front door Premium.  Origin group is not provided such because it's a premium service offered.  Hope it will be available in future on Classic soon.

NOTE:
Private endpoint connection should be approved to allow traffic to origin

Comment: Yes, I hope this comes to Classic soon as well, thank you!